# sql join or subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

First of all thank you for read this.

I want to do a query between 2 tables, but i don't know how to do it.

I have a table called `products` and another called `product_photos`. I want to query ALL the `products` and in every lane of the result, add two fields from the table `product_photos`. The problem is when I execute my query works but only show the first field from `product_photos`, and I want to show every lane.

I got this:

```
select p.*, ps.url_little, ps.url_big
from product p
     LEFT join product_photos ps
         on (p.id_prod = ps.id_product)
```

How can I do this? Do I have to do subquery or union? Thank you all.

EDIT:

example of json result:

`{\"id\":\"1\",\"id_prod\":\"375843\",\"ref\":\"5943853\",\"ean\":\"894378432831283\",\"concept\":\"Portamatr\\u00edculas Barracuda\",\"description\":\"Portamatr\\u00edculas Barracuda FZ6 a\\u00f1o 2004-2008\",\"price\":\"19.99\",\"old_price\":\"25.58\",\"category\":\"Motor\",\"family\":\"Accesorio veh\\u00edculo a motor\",\"sub_family\":\"Accesorio veh\\u00edculo a motor de dos ruedas\",\"gender\":\"\",\"sub_gender\":\"\",\"photo\":\"\",\"thumbnail\":\"\",\"type\":\"1\",\"size\":\"\",\"color\":\"\",\"weave\":\"\",\"motiu\":\"\",\"material\":\"\",\"artist\":\"\",\"technique\":\"\",\"paper\":\"\",\"tittle\":\"\",\"measure\":\"\",\"edition\":\"\",\"status\":\"\",\"reference\":\"\",\"cost\":\"0\",\"url_little\":\"urllittlee kgjhdfjfd\",\"url_big\":\"url bigota\"}`

As you can see, i got the two fields, url_little and url_big, but only from 1 field, and I got two in the table product_photos. I want both to appear.

Second edit, i'm terrible explaining my problems, sorry:

I receive this json:

`{\"id\":\"1\",\"id_prod\":\"375843\",\"ref\":\"5943853\",\"ean\":\"894378432831283\",\"concept\":\"Portamatr\\u00edculas Barracuda\",\"description\":\"Portamatr\\u00edculas Barracuda FZ6 a\\u00f1o 2004-2008\",\"price\":\"19.99\",\"old_price\":\"25.58\",\"category\":\"Motor\",\"family\":\"Accesorio veh\\u00edculo a motor\",\"sub_family\":\"Accesorio veh\\u00edculo a motor de dos ruedas\",\"gender\":\"\",\"sub_gender\":\"\",\"photo\":\"\",\"thumbnail\":\"\",\"type\":\"1\",\"size\":\"\",\"color\":\"\",\"weave\":\"\",\"motiu\":\"\",\"material\":\"\",\"artist\":\"\",\"technique\":\"\",\"paper\":\"\",\"tittle\":\"\",\"measure\":\"\",\"edition\":\"\",\"status\":\"\",\"reference\":\"\",\"cost\":\"0\",\"url_little\":\"urllittlee kgjhdfjfd\",\"url_big\":\"url bigota\"},{\"id\":\"1\",\"id_prod\":\"375843\",\"ref\":\"5943853\",\"ean\":\"894378432831283\",\"concept\":\"Portamatr\\u00edculas Barracuda\",\"description\":\"Portamatr\\u00edculas Barracuda FZ6 a\\u00f1o 2004-2008\",\"price\":\"19.99\",\"old_price\":\"25.58\",\"category\":\"Motor\",\"family\":\"Accesorio veh\\u00edculo a motor\",\"sub_family\":\"Accesorio veh\\u00edculo a motor de dos ruedas\",\"gender\":\"\",\"sub_gender\":\"\",\"photo\":\"\",\"thumbnail\":\"\",\"type\":\"1\",\"size\":\"\",\"color\":\"\",\"weave\":\"\",\"motiu\":\"\",\"material\":\"\",\"artist\":\"\",\"technique\":\"\",\"paper\":\"\",\"tittle\":\"\",\"measure\":\"\",\"edition\":\"\",\"status\":\"\",\"reference\":\"\",\"cost\":\"0\",\"url_little\":\"SISI\",\"url_big\":\"NONO\"}`

and I want to receive this:

`{\"id\":\"1\",\"id_prod\":\"375843\",\"ref\":\"5943853\",\"ean\":\"894378432831283\",\"concept\":\"Portamatr\\u00edculas Barracuda\",\"description\":\"Portamatr\\u00edculas Barracuda FZ6 a\\u00f1o 2004-2008\",\"price\":\"19.99\",\"old_price\":\"25.58\",\"category\":\"Motor\",\"family\":\"Accesorio veh\\u00edculo a motor\",\"sub_family\":\"Accesorio veh\\u00edculo a motor de dos ruedas\",\"gender\":\"\",\"sub_gender\":\"\",\"photo\":\"\",\"thumbnail\":\"\",\"type\":\"1\",\"size\":\"\",\"color\":\"\",\"weave\":\"\",\"motiu\":\"\",\"material\":\"\",\"artist\":\"\",\"technique\":\"\",\"paper\":\"\",\"tittle\":\"\",\"measure\":\"\",\"edition\":\"\",\"status\":\"\",\"reference\":\"\",\"cost\":\"0\",\"url_little\":\"urllittlee kgjhdfjfd , SISI\",\"url_big\":\"url bigota, NONO\"}`

As u can see, in the fields url_little and url_big are all the results, not only the first one.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give a sample of the result you get, and the result you would like? Your query looks ok to me.

Comment: Your query is correct.  Perhaps you have a column called `url_little` or `url_big` in `product`.

Comment: I think your query is correct. Let's show me a sample example!

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is not an issue here since he references column names with a table specifier. @ AlexPerez Could you please explain what "only the first field from product_photos" means? Do you only get ps.url_little in your results?

Comment: Edit done. Maybe i didn't explain good (probably..)

Comment: Your output is json. Mysql doesn't naturally output json. So maybe your problem is how you process the result, not the query itself. Is there some php or something that's running? What if you just run the query via the command-line?

Comment: I still don't get your problem. If you really want ALL photos, then use a `full outer join`. But this would only add results if you have photos in yor table which do not belong to a product.

Comment: Editted again. Maybe i'm the worst guy explaining what I want, I'm sorry!

Comment: I think what you want is a group by and a group_concat. I've added an answer that will hopefully work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the final edit, I think this is what you want. It uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to join all the values in the linked table together.

```
select p.*,
group_concat(ps.url_little SEPARATOR ', '),
group_concat(ps.url_big SEPARATOR ', ')
from product p
     LEFT join product_photos ps
         on (p.id_prod = ps.id_product)
group by p.id_prod
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the FULL OUTER JOIN keyword. 
In your case that would mean something like this:

```
SELECT p.*, ps.url_little, ps.url_big from 
FROM product p
FULL OUTER JOIN product_photos ps
ON (p.id_prod = ps.id_product);
```

This will leave you with the full array of photos of a product.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT p.*, ps.urls_little, ps.urls_big
FROM product p
    LEFT join
(SELECT id_product, GROUP_CONCAT(url_little) AS urls_little, GROUP_CONCAT(url_big) AS urls_big FROM product_photos GROUP BY id_product) AS ps
ON (p.id_prod = ps.id_product)
```

Here is a really small fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aae09/7

`GROUP_CONCAT` is vendor specific and not part of the SQL standard. In other DBMS you should look at `listagg` (Oracle), `string_agg` (Postgres), and so on. Most important takeaway: You cannot run your code without modifications on different systems.